# Capture a Regex group and use it instead for the search

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large html text file that has some inconsistency in ending a paragraph with full-stop.

Below is an example.

```
<p>Text ending with a full-stop.</p>
<p>Text ending without a full-stop</p>
```

I want to search for all paragraph that doesn't end with full stop and add a full-stop to it.

Note: am using Notepad++ for the regex search.

How do i do that?

I came up with this `[^.](?:</p>)` which matches paragraph without fullstop together with the `</p>` tag.

If only i could use the capture group to do the regex search instead and then replace it with `.</p>`

Anybody know how i can resolve this?

Comment: @JDB, If it's a simple search and replace in Sublime for example, "why do you feel the need" to use HTML parsers and lexers? And it's not complicated, and, _amazingly_, **[is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29184775/865175)** possible to accomplish with a single regex. Also, Regex **===** Magic!.

Comment: Always tag the language/program that you're using when asking a regex question. It's like asking about English grammar, without specifying whether you mean England's, Australian, American, etc, English.

Comment: @cfqueryparam Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `([^.])(?=<\/p>)` that translates to:

> Match any character that isn't a dot and is followed by `</p>`

You can then use the backreference of the first group to add the missing dot by replacing with `\1.` as seen in [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU3dJ9/2) I created.